# Messed-up triangles when using VertexPositionColorTexture with BasicEffect

Tags: xna, 3d, c#

Image of the problem:

[image: image of the problem]

I used [Microsoft's BasicEffect tutorial here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=198921) and [the code sample here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=198921) and got everything to work fine. Next, I changed everything to use vertexPositionNormalTexture, added a few small methods to help with the texture, and was able to render a textured cube just fine. I also made the cube spin a bit. Next, I wanted to try using vertexPositionNormalTexture.  Unfortunately, I got this image instead of a cube. Here are some pieces of my code that contain major modifications.

Draw method

```
 protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.SteelBlue);

            RasterizerState rasterizerState1 = new RasterizerState();
            //backface culling
            rasterizerState1.CullMode = CullMode.None;
            //turn off texture blurring
            graphics.GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.PointClamp;


            graphics.GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = rasterizerState1;
            foreach (EffectPass pass in basicEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
            {
                pass.Apply();
                graphics.GraphicsDevice.DrawPrimitives(
                    PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 
                    0, 
                    12
                );
            } 

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
```

Part of the method that sets up vertices

```
private void InitializeCube()
    {

        Vector3 topLeftFront = new Vector3(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        Vector3 bottomLeftFront = new Vector3(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        Vector3 topRightFront = new Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        Vector3 bottomRightFront = new Vector3(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        Vector3 topLeftBack = new Vector3(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
        Vector3 topRightBack = new Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
        Vector3 bottomLeftBack = new Vector3(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        Vector3 bottomRightBack = new Vector3(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

        Vector2 textureTopLeft = new Vector2(0.0f, 0.0f);
        Vector2 textureTopRight = new Vector2(.25f, 0.0f);
        Vector2 textureBottomLeft = new Vector2(0.0f, .25f);
        Vector2 textureBottomRight = new Vector2(.25f, .25f);

        Color frontColor = new Color(255, 255, 255);
        Color backColor = new Color(255, 0, 0);
        Color topColor = new Color(0, 255, 0);
        Color bottomColor = new Color(0, 0, 255);
        Color leftColor = new Color(0, 255, 255);
        Color rightColor = new Color(0, 0, 0);

        // Front face.
        cubeVertices[0] =
            new VertexPositionColorTexture(
            topLeftFront, frontColor, GetTexPos(2));
        cubeVertices[1] =
            new VertexPositionColorTexture(
            bottomLeftFront, frontColor, GetTexPos(2) + textureBottomLeft);
        cubeVertices[2] =
            new VertexPositionColorTexture(
            topRightFront, frontColor, GetTexPos(2) + textureTopRight);
        cubeVertices[3] =
            new VertexPositionColorTexture(
            bottomLeftFront, frontColor, GetTexPos(2) + textureBottomLeft);
        cubeVertices[4] =
            new VertexPositionColorTexture(
            bottomRightFront, frontColor, GetTexPos(2) + textureBottomRight);
        cubeVertices[5] =
            new VertexPositionColorTexture(
            topRightFront, frontColor, GetTexPos(2) + textureTopRight);
```

Initializing `basicEffect`

```
private void InitializeEffect()
    {
        basicEffect = new BasicEffect(graphics.GraphicsDevice);


        basicEffect.World = worldMatrix;
        basicEffect.View = viewMatrix;
        basicEffect.Projection = projectionMatrix;

        //basicEffect.EnableDefaultLighting
    }
```

LoadContent

```
protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        canyonTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("CanyonTexture");
        textureSheetWidth = canyonTexture.Width / 16;
        InitializeTransform();
        InitializeEffect();
        basicEffect.TextureEnabled = true;
        basicEffect.VertexColorEnabled = true;
        basicEffect.Texture = canyonTexture;

        InitializeCube();

    }
```

Setting up the `VertexBuffer`

```
private void CreateVertexBuffer()
    {
        vertexDeclaration = new VertexDeclaration(new VertexElement[]
            {
                new VertexElement(0, VertexElementFormat.Vector3, VertexElementUsage.Position, 0),
                new VertexElement(12, VertexElementFormat.Color, VertexElementUsage.Color, 0),
                new VertexElement(24, VertexElementFormat.Vector2, VertexElementUsage.TextureCoordinate, 0)
            });

        vertexBuffer = new VertexBuffer(
            graphics.GraphicsDevice,
            vertexDeclaration,
            number_of_vertices,
            BufferUsage.None
            );


        cubeVertices = new VertexPositionColorTexture[number_of_vertices];
        InitializeCube();


        vertexBuffer.SetData<VertexPositionColorTexture>(cubeVertices);

        graphics.GraphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer);
    }


    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        // TODO: Add your initialization logic here
        CreateVertexBuffer();

        base.Initialize();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically your vertex declaration is wrong.

A `Color` is only four bytes wide. So the offset of the texture-coordinate element that follows should be 16, not 24.

However you don't even need to create a vertex declaration for this in XNA 4.0. Simply pass `VertexPositionColorTexture.VertexDeclaration` or `typeof(VertexPositionColorTexture)` to the constructor of your `VertexBuffer`.

There is a [blog post here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160108182729/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/04/19/vertex-data-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx) that explains how this all works.

Comment: Thanks .  (My post on two sites gets the same great answer from same great person :D)